# random and occurrences

Tags: ruby, random, iteration

I'm trying to create a program that:

- asks the user to input a max. range (a)
- asks the user to input a max. number of iterations (b)
- N = 1 (N is number of iterations)

then

- for N < b generate a random number between 0 and a
- count number of occurrences of every number that was generated

and at the end

- puts number = number of occurrences of the number
  (for every number)

I tried a lot of things but I really feel that I'm making it too complicated and obviously not working.

```
puts "range :"
$Sur = gets.to_f

$N = 1
$Iterations = 1

while ($N <= 50) do

  def rand
    num1 = 0
    num2 = 0
    num3 = 0
    num4 = 0
    num5 = 0
    num6 = 0
    num7 = 0
    num8 = 0
    num9 = 0
    num10 = 0

    r = [*0..$Sur].sample
    if (r == 1)
        num1 += 1
      elsif (r == 2)
        num2 += 1
      elsif (r == 3)
        num3 += 1
      elsif (r == 4)
        num4 += 1
      elsif (r == 5)
        num5 += 1
      elsif (r == 6)
        num6 += 1
      elsif (r == 7)
        num7 += 1
      elsif (r == 8)
        num8 += 1
      elsif (r == 9)
        num9 += 1
      elsif (r == 10)
        num10 += 1
    end

    occurence = array.[](num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10)
    puts "#{occurrence}"

  end

puts "r = #{rand}"+"  i = #{$Iterations}"
puts "Nombre de fois 1=#{num1}"
puts "Nombre de fois 2=#{num2}"
puts "Nombre de fois 3=#{num3}"
puts "Nombre de fois 4=#{num4}"
puts "Nombre de fois 5=#{num5}"
puts "Nombre de fois 6=#{num6}"
puts "Nombre de fois 7=#{num7}"
puts "Nombre de fois 8=#{num8}"
puts "Nombre de fois 9=#{num9}"
puts "Nombre de fois 10=#{num10}"

  $N += 1
  $Iterations = $N-1

end

  puts "_________________________________________________"
  puts "Fin de l\'algorithme."
  puts "\n"
  puts "N est superieur au maximum que vous avez entrer"
  puts "Nombre d\'iterations de N = #{$Iterations}"
  puts "_________________________________________________"
```

Comment: No ^^ Absolutely not. I just want to test the "randomness" of the implementation of the random generator in ruby !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
upper  = 10
count  = 50
result = Hash.new(0)

count.times do
  result[rand(upper)+1]+=1
end

(1..upper).each do |num|
  puts "Nombre de fois #{num} = #{result[num]}"
end
```

Comment: Ouaou thanks this really helped ! Could you explain me the (1..upper) ?

Comment: That makes a range from 1 to the current value of `upper` - if you want to see this yourself type `(1..upper).to_a` into irb (`to_a` means "to array") :-) Looking at your code above, it's similar to what you were doing with `[*0..$Sur]` (an equivalent would be `[*1..upper]`).

Comment: Oh ok thx ! =) Most of the time I keep doing some very long nested if or elsif and it gets more and more complicated to read and to correct. Most of the time it's because I don't really know how to use the iterations or counting.